# Why not always android:configChanges="orientation"?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

When my phone is rotating then my activity is restarting why not always using

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in manifest?

Is  there any bug which can cause if i will use it always?

Comment: For adaptive layouts, you might have a different layout for portrait vs landscape.

Comment: My application is locked only as landscape

Comment: Than it does not matter

Comment: Does it cost any extra ram or cpu(performance) if i will not restart my activity on rotation?

Comment: Not at all... of course the layout that you are using will get invalidated so all the ViewGroups/Views sizes/positions can be calculated.

Comment: I dont have any problem neither with positions or sizes when it rotates. I cant find the reason which not to use it. The only thing which i dont know is,  if other mobiles have different behaviour.

Comment: either try to handle data stat with bundle in onSavedInstanceState and use that or one anohter thing - try using     android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
this inside your activity tag.